# Not for the App Store - Can someone show me where to find system volume code?

Tags: iphone, ios, system, volume, iphone-privateapi

For my personal use only !!!

I am trying to find where I can change the system volume inside an app. I just want to make something that when I press a button it turns down the brightness and lowers the volume (ringtone) and when I am in a meeting I can set a different "profile".

I would use this a lot since I am in classes and meetings during the day.

Any help? I have heard about the celestial framework, but I can't find it anywhere. Is that what i need.

Again, this is not for apple's approval:-) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the brightness you can use following code (and it's even public)

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness: brightness];
```

where `brightness` is some float from 0.0 to 1.0.

For the volume. Try following (these are private APIs in **SpringboardService** framework)

```
mach_port_t SBSSpringBoardServerPort();

void SBSetMediaVolume(mach_port_t port, int volume);
```

In the case, if it won't work. You can try to use `GSEvent` with code `kGSEventVolumeDownButtonDown`, `kGSEventVolumeDownButtonUp`, `kGSEventVolumeUpButtonDown`, `kGSEventVolumeUpButtonUp`

The reference implementation is here:
http://code.google.com/p/hid-support/source/browse/trunk/hidspringboard/Tweak.xm?spec=svn82&r=82

It's jailbreak tweak. However, you can extract the code and it should work on non jailbroken phone.